# Error when trying to make a method with delay

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Trying to call this method with delay:

```
  LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(GoogleApiClient, LocationRequest, (LocationListener) this);
```

I found on stack this method that causes delay:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do something after 100ms
  }
}, 100);
```

But when i trying to call this method like this:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(GoogleApiClient, LocationRequest, (LocationListener) this);
  }
}, 100);
```

Android studio change this for

```
       final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    return;
                }
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, (LocationListener) this);
            }
        }, 100);
```

and now my problem, android studio highlighted errors:

`this` in `(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)`

`this` in `(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)`

and `(LocationListener) this` in `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, (LocationListener) this);`

What to do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, `this` is a keyword that references the context to which the method your executing is in. `this` in the run() method is actually referring to the Runnable() class created by your Handler.

You need to pass in your activity context to the Runnable() and use that in those methods.

Comment: Is there a easier way ? I dont know how to do this context and runnable() :(

Comment: It's not that hard. Right above your "handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {" parts, just do final Activity activity = this; (Or if your in a Fragment use getActivity()). Then in the run() method just replace "this" with "activity"

Comment: This must be the name of my current activity or doesn't matter what name?

Comment: Variable name doesn't really matter, but specifying {ActivityName}.this might be more clear.